# SQL- JOIN two column from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union

I need help to formulate a query. I want to select all DISTINCT colors from TABLE A and TABLE B.

This is the wanted result from the query:

```
BLACK
RED
YELLOW
BLUE
```

I have these tables:

TABLE A

```
ID   NAME    COLOR
5    SOCKS   BLACK
4    SOCKS   RED
```

TABLE B

```
ID   NAME   COLOR 
0    CAR    BLUE
1    BIKE   BLUE
5    TRUCK  YELLOW
10   PLANE  NULL
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.color FROM A JOIN B ON b.color
```

But I don't get all the colors. :(

Comment: Your join syntax is incorrect.  There is no relation between table a and table b.  You need to `UNION` the set of tuples into one set of tuples.  See my answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot about UNION :((

Comment: if you resolved your issue please ACCEPT an answer so we can mark this question as CLOSED.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT color FROM A
UNION
SELECT color FROM B
WHERE  color IS NOT NULL -- only filters NULL from B
ORDER  BY color          -- sorts all rows
```

`UNION` (instead of `UNION ALL`) removes duplicates. No need for additional subqueries or `DISTINCT`.

Comment: I think this will not remove any nulls coming from `TableA`

Comment: @ypercube: That's correct, but on purpose. The example only features a `NULL` value in table `B`. To filter `NULL` from both tables add the same WHERE clause under table `A`. [Working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2c71/1).

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
  A.Color FROM TableA A
WHERE A.Color IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT
  B.Color FROM TableB B
    WHERE B.Color IS NOT NULL
```

I removed DISTINCT because it is not necessary when you combine it with UNION - I always tend to forget this!.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Color
FROM (
    SELECT Color FROM TableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Color FROM TableB
) Colors
WHERE NOT Color IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But how can i remove all NULL values ??

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter answer looks better than mine actually... didn't realise UNION had these properties.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0de4d/5

```
SELECT distinct
    COLOR
FROM
    (
      select color from TableA
      UNION
      select color from TableB
    ) tmp
WHERE color IS NOT NULL
order by color
```

*edited* to remove nulls

Full disclosure - SQL Fiddle is my site

Comment: I **love** your site sqlfiddle, btw! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT color FROM 
(
    (
        (SELECT color FROM A WHERE color IS NOT NULL)
        UNION 
        (SELECT color FROM B WHERE color IS NOT NULL)
    ) AS temp
)
```